# JavaScript XPath on childNodes, evaluate is not a function

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I'm using plain JavaScript to parse an xml result using a `DOMParser`. I want to iterate over certain nodes, and do some processing on each one of them.

Problem is, after getting the nodes in question via `childNodes` I can't run an XPath evaluate on those nodes. Do I have to somehow cast the nodes to xml again? Or maybe use a different function?

I've got some experience with xpath in SQL Server, but not in JavaScript, so it's probably a pretty dumb question.

Here's my xml

```
<result>
  <entry>
    <component typeCode="COMP">
      <sequenceNumber value="1" />
      <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="DEF">
        <code displayName="StartDate" code="CODE_041" />
        <value xsi:type="TS" />
      </observation>
    </component>
    <component typeCode="COMP">
      <sequenceNumber value="2" />
      <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="DEF">
        <code displayName="Amount" code="CODE_045" />
        <value xsi:type="PQ" value="000000000000000.00" />
      </observation>
    </component>
  </entry>
</result>
```

And the javascript code

```
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmltext, "text/xml");

        var ent = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry");

        // get child nodes
        var chil = ent[0].childNodes;
        for (var c = 0; c < chil.length; c++) {
            var nod = chil[c];
            // component
            if (nod.tagName == "component") {

                // error "evaluate is not a function"
                var field_code = nod.evaluate("/observation/code[@code]", nod, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
                var field_name = nod.evaluate("/observation/code[@displayName]", nod, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
            };
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out why that happens (xpath should work all the way), but since I could get to the end result another way, I figured I might as well post it in case it helps. If not, no harm done, I guess.

```
xpath = require('xpath')
 , dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser; 
let xmlDoc = new dom().parseFromString(xmltext);

let ent = xpath.select("//component//observation/code", xmlDoc);
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(ent)) {
  let field_code = `${value.getAttribute('code')}`;
  let field_name = `${value.getAttribute('displayName')}`;
   console.log('field code: ',field_code,'display name: ',field_name)
}
```

Output:

```
field code:  CODE_041 display name:  StartDate
field code:  CODE_045 display name:  Amount
```